# Create javascript object dynamic in a foreach loop

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to create objects in a foreach loop:

I'm starting from this:

```
data.forEach(function (el) {
        var dynamic_var = new Quill(el['editor']);
         dynamic_var.on('text-change', logHtmlContent);})
```

But, dynamic_var is 'overwritten', and I want to remain unique.

I check some html elements, and for each one that I found I want to create a new Object, and execute the Object methods.

In my case the variable get a new object per each iteration, is not a new variable.

Comment: What do you mean 'overwritten'? What is expected and current behavior?

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov At first I thought OP meant that it gets overwritten by the last element, since `var` is used instead of `let`. But then I saw it's inside a `foreach` function so it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov  I mean the variable becomes every time a new Quill object, and I don't want to lose them, but simple creating multiple objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
var quillValueContainer = {};

// ...

data.forEach(function(el) {
  quillValueContainer[el] = new Quill(el['editor']);
  quillValueContainer[el].on('text-change', logHtmlContent);
});
```

This will only work if `el` is a string, or number. Seeing how you are using it like this: `el['editor']`, makes me thing it's an `Object`, in which case, you can instead use the indices of the elements.

```
var quillValueContainer = {}; // [] should also work for indexes

// ...

data.forEach(function(el, index) {
  quillValueContainer[index] = new Quill(el['editor']);
  quillValueContainer[index].on('text-change', logHtmlContent);
});
```

Also, I don't know if this is something you need to do, but you can check if the `Quill` Object has already been initialized and skipping a duplication if it has, by doing:

```
data.filter(function(el, index){ return !quillValueContainer[index]; }).foreach(...
```

Or

```
data.forEach(function(el, index) {
  if(quillValueContainer[index]) return;
  quillValueContainer[index] = new Quill(el['editor']);
  quillValueContainer[index].on('text-change', logHtmlContent);
});
```

Comment: thank you, can you please take a look at this one(related) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54483529/quill-editor-the-on-method-works-only-once

Comment: @user3541631 posted an answer there as well