# Quill Editor, The 'on' method works only once

Tags: quill

I have the following, script for the QuillEditor(I have multiple editors):

```
var editors = {};
        function editors() {
     var toolbarOptions = [
                        [{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
                    ];
                    data.forEach(function (el) {
                        editors[el] = new Quill(el['editor'], {modules: {toolbar: toolbarOptions}, theme: 'snow', scrollingContainer:el['quill'] });
                        editors[el].on('text-change', copyText(el['text'], editors[el]));
                    });
                }
        }
                function copyText(text, editor) {
                    text.innerHTML = editor.root.innerHTML;
                    console.log(text.innerHTML)
                }
```

To use it in backend, I'm copying the text from the editor to a textarea `copyText(el['text']`.

I need to always work, but it is coping text/html, only once when the function is executed. I'm expecting  editors[el].on('text-change', to work like an event listener.

The `scrollingContainer`, doesn't a scroll. I check that the target exist, is the parent of the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this part of the error but you have an extra `}` after after the `editors` function.

The main problem here is that instead of setting the event listener you are running the event listener which is why it is running only once.

So change the event-listener line to:

```
editors[el].on('text-change', function () {
    copyText(el['text'], editors[el]);
});
```

I don't generally like creating functions in other functions and especially inside loops so I would recommend creating a function factory function that will create a new function for each element.

```
function createListener(text, editor) {
    return function(){
        copyText(text, editor);
    };
}
```

And call it like this:

```
editors[el].on('text-change', createListener(el['text'], editors[el]));
```